# Best way to store a list of objects with geo data in Redis

Tags: mysql, caching, cakephp

It would be great if someone can help me. I am trying to implement Radis cache in my cakephp framework project.

In my project there is module thats data is used very frequently with mysql query update & select. So i planned to keep thats module data in radis cache.

following is schema of object that i want to keep in cache

```
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_login` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=>on walk,1=>on run',
  `manual_busy` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'used when user mark himself busy',
  `is_idle` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'keep record if user moving or not',
  `lat` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'where the user is at present',
  `lng` varchar(20) NOT NULL
```

now after saving these type of object i want to search nearest user based on some conditions like "status=1" and "owner_id=2" and "manual_busy=0"

for nearest user comparison i will have geo latitude-longitude.

I checked Radis document and found some geo function 
https://redis.io/commands/georadius
but georadius command does not work for HMSET keys.

Please suggest a solution if anyone worked on same feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the GEOADD command to create a sorted set of user locations, then instead of storing the lat/lng in the user object, store the key you used when adding that user's location to the geo set.

So for example

```
GEOADD Locations 41.8883 -87.6323 "User1"
HMSET userhashkey geokey "User1"
```

Then once you get the list of users that you want to search for geographically, you can compare the values in the geokey field with the results of the GEORADIUS command.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you provide an example of comparing the geokey with results of the GEORADIUS?